# Release memory in Swift in UIImage and UIImageViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, autorelease

I'm developing an application that consists of multiple Views. Each view contains several animations which are formed by UIImageView.animate. The problem I have is that every time I open a new View memory is not reduced, is increasing up to 320 Mb on an iPhone 4, retonrando a memory error "Terminated due to memory error." I can not find how to autorelease memory in Swift, since in Objective-C if I could see it's more advisable to use
imageWithContentOfFile instead of named:  ...

I use this to add image to a UIImage object:

```
var leftCorner: UIImage =  UIImage(named: "navegacio_esquerra")!
```

To add a Array of images in the UIImageView.animationImages I use this:

```
var thirdSisterHeadList: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 33, 32, 33, 34, 33, 32, 33, 34, 33, 32, 33, 34, 33, 32, 33, 34, 33, 66, 67, 68]

        var thirdSisterHeadImageList: [UIImage] = []

        for i in thirdSisterHeadList{
            var imageName = "pantalla_12_03_caps_c_\(i).png"
            thirdSisterHeadImageList += [UIImage(named: imageName)!]
        }
thirdSisterHead.animationImages = thirdSisterHeadImageList
```

Answer (score 1):

This comment doesn't make sense

> I can not find how to autorelease memory in Swift, since in Objective-C if I could see it's more advisable to use imageWithContentOfFile instead of named:.

Swift and ObjC manage memory identically. And for this kind of work, you'd definitely want to use `named:` since that allows the system to perform much better memory management for you. when memory is tight, it can automatically purge the representations that aren't needed.

Start with the Allocations instrument in Instruments. Make sure that these images are actually where your memory is going to. It's likely the case, but with memory profiling you want data, not guesses.

You're using the same images more than once. That's probably fine, but you should validate that each instance of `pantalla_12_03_caps_c_33.png` is in fact the same `UIImage` (this really should work for you automatically, so I don't strongly suspect a problem here).

To animate the image, it's going to want them all decoded in memory. Even so, 320MB for 30 images on a iPhone 4 sounds like a lot. That's ~10MB per image. A full-screen iPhone 4 image should be more like 2MB (640*960*4). If you're using very high-resolution images, you may want to provide multiple resolutions for different devices so it doesn't have to deal with so much data that it's going to throw away.

The fact that the memory isn't being recovered almost certainly means your view isn't being released. That suggests that you have a retain loop, or perhaps you keep calling `addSubview:` to add an image view without removing the old image view (this is a pretty common mistake). Override `dealloc` in your view controller and make sure it's going away when you expect it to. Make sure you're not holding onto `thirdSisterHead` somewhere outside of this view controller.

Unrelated side note: your for-in loop is really doing this the hard way. This code can be simplified and all the variables replaced with constants, and eliminate the need to create a temporary `[UIImage]` for the `+=`:

```
let thirdSisterHeadList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 33, 32, 33, 34, 33, 32, 33, 34, 33, 32, 33, 34, 33, 32, 33, 34, 33, 66, 67, 68]
let thirdSisterHeadImageList = thirdSisterHeadList.map { 
    UIImage(named: "pantalla_12_03_caps_c_\($0).png")! 
}
self.thirdSisterHead.animationImages = thirdSisterHeadImageList
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. First comment that indeed is that memory management is identical in Obj-C and Swift, but in all searches I've done on this topic using the method recommended me use named:  instead of method imageWithContentOfFile :, is why I've done this comment. On the other hand, the images that I charge does not occupy more than 12Kb, the 320MB is the accumulation of all aplication. On the other hand, I tried to override dealloc, but Swift can not overwrite dealoc as this marked as unavailable.

Comment: Your understanding that `named:` is better is correct for this case. Note that images require memory proportional to their total, uncompressed displayed size, not just their compressed size on disk, but it is unlikely that a 12kb file is being blown up to that level. In Swift, `dealloc` is now called `deinit`. You should use Heapshot in Instruments to determine how much memory you're leaking per action.

Comment: Ok, but, How is used deinit to release the necessary space??

Comment: You don't use `deinit` to release anything. You use `deinit` to find out whether your view controller is actually being destroyed (by adding a log statement). If it isn't, you have a retain loop that you need to address.

Comment: Maybe my problem is deeper than this, since I'm developing is a children's story which is composed of 14 scenes with 3 or 4 animations every scene. Each scene'm developing a storyboard for each scene and a VC for each scene. To create animations, I assign an array of images to animationImage and a float indicating the time duration of the animation in animationDuration in a UIImageView. When running the Segue the VC 1al VC 2 as I can empty the entire contents of the VC one ?? I apologize and appreciate all the help you can provide me. thank you very much

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to hold all the VCs and animations in memory at the same time. You probably want to use things like `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` to help reduce memory usage. You also may want to investigate a `UIPageController` to manage page transitions. It's built so you only need to hold a few pages in memory at the same time (those displayed, plus the ones immediate preceding and following).

Comment: An much as I loathe JavaScript, I've had very good luck building small eBooks on iPad with `UIWebView`. HTML5 is pretty well suited to text and graphic layout problems with animations.

Comment: Ok, but in the project I need to develop 6 mini Games. Is these the reason cause I use native and not JS and HTML5. That I don't understand is what I have to put inside the method viewWillDesapear to empty? I am currently using the method viewWillAppear to prostrate content. You are my idol from today!!!

Comment: You should drop any data that you no longer need in viewWilDisappear. For example, you could set your animation images to nil. (BTW, it is very easy to stick iOS views into a `UIWebView` at any point you like. So mixing isn't a problem. Here's a play project that I was experimenting with to demonstrate: https://github.com/rnapier/WebBook)

Comment: Is this ok:     override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        self.image.animationImages = nil
        self.bee.animationImages = nil
        self.view = nil
        self.imageList.removeAll()
        self.abellaImageList.removeAll()
        
    }

Comment: It's definitely a start to see if that cleans up memory. If not, then that's not where your issue is. Again, Instruments and the Memory Allocations and Leaks tools should be your first step.

Comment: Ok, I see in Allocations that all PNG images are always retained, not disappear from Memory Allocations. For every ViewController, in Allocations generate ImageIO_PNG_Data / ImageIO / ImageIO_Malloc for each png file I load in the view. In Leaks I have only one warning with AVAudioPlayer. I think it's good idea to make in HTML but now I have 13 scenes developed and need to publish in 5 days. I take this into account in upcoming projects.

Comment: Is possible develop this iOS Swift App With SpriteKit + UIPageViewController??